# how to use signal frameChanged(int) to play the QMovie once in QT

Tags: c++, qt

how to use frameChanged(int) to decide the frame is the last frame, i want to use the signal to stop the Qmovie to play it once instead of forever.

```
QMovie *movie = new QMovie();
movie->setFileName("C:/Qt/qtcreator-2.2.1/game/test/pikaqiu.gif");
QSize size = this->getLabelPointer()->size();
movie->setScaledSize(size);
this->getLabelPointer()->setMovie(movie);
QObject::connect(movie,SIGNAL(finished()),movie,SLOT(deleteLater()));
movie->start();
enter code here
delete this;
movie->stop();
```

`

Comment: Do you want to detect when you get the last frame?

Comment: Yes..............

Comment: Why do not you use the finished () signal, does this tell you when QVideo ends?

Comment: The QMovie will loop, and the finished() won't be emitted.

Comment: Or do you really want the QVideo to play forever?

Comment: In very few cases a loop in Qt is used, it is not recommended. You could share your code to understand yourself better.

Comment: I want to play it once.

Comment: I do not understand you, explain yourself better.

Comment: Please correct your code

Comment: see my answer :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the `frameCount()` function to get the number of frames of QMovie.

```
QMovie *movie = new QMovie();
movie->setFileName("download.gif");
ui->label->setMovie(movie);

connect(movie, &QMovie::frameChanged, [=](int frameNumber){
    if(frameNumber == movie->frameCount()-1){
        movie->stop();
        movie->deleteLater();
    }
});
movie->start();
```

Comment: Please if my answer helps you mark it as correct please

Comment: 'void QMovie::frameChanged(int)' is protected,how to deal with it?

Comment: What version of Qt do you use? frameChanged is a signal: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmovie.html#frameChanged

Comment: the version is 4.7.4

Comment: From where you say it is a protected method, I have reviewed the documentation for that version: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qmovie.html#frameChanged and it is not protected. What exactly is your error message?

Comment: I've used a new style of signal and slots connection, but I think you can implement it for your version easily. But share your code through github, drive or similar to help you

Comment: @Rex: reputation is the only reward to the time spent in helping. Voting helpful answer up is also a good idea. Maybe they will also vote your question which help you.

Comment: Share me your code through Github, drive or similar